# Get remaining split string on PHP after explode

Tags: php, arrays, string, function, explode

I want to be able to get the remaining string after an explode.

```
$string = "First Middle Last";
$d = explode(" ", $string);
print_r($d);

Outputs:
$d = array
(
  [0] => First
  [1] => Middle
  [2] => Last
)

$first = $d[0]; // First
$last = $d[1] // Middle
```

How can I get the last and remaining exploded values?

I want to be able to do:

```
$last = $d[last?] // Middle Last
```

I do not want to do

```
$last = $d[1].$d[2] // Middle Last
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should probably use the third (optional) argument of `explode`:

```
list ($first, $last) = explode(" ", $string, 2);
```

That said, splitting on spaces is going to work on a lot of human names, but will also fail for quite significant percentage if you take the global view. There's nothing wrong with doing it as a practical solution to a particular problem, just don't expect that it will always work correctly.

Comment: This is the easiest fix. Thanks for that extra parameter on explode. It worked!

Answer (score 3):

You could use `array_slice`. This will indefinitely work for any strings.

```
<?php
$string = "First Middle Last Next Over";
echo implode(' ',array_slice(explode(" ", $string),1));
```

**`OUTPUT :`**

```
Middle Last Next Over
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$string = "First Middle Last";

preg_match_all("/\s(.*)/", $string , $output_array);

echo $output_array[1][0];

Output // Middle Last
```

Or simply

```
preg_match("/\s(.*)/", $string , $output_array);

echo $output_array[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
$string = "First Middle Last";
list($d1,$d2,$d3) = explode(" ", $string);
print_r($d1);
print_r($d2);
print_r($d3);
```